# Console not printing lines and/or words

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, console, console-application

I have a simple code just to have fun, it was supposed to print the entire alphabet, each letter separated from each other with 100 empty lines... But this is not printing any line....

Note: Before I used code similar to this and it worked (obviously the other was real code and didn't have the 100 lines thingy)
"alfabeto" = "alphabet" (Portuguese word, I was not going to translate 26 lines if I could just say this)

```
namespace Alfabeto_das_100_linhas
{
    class Inicial
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] alfabeto = new string[26];
            alfabeto[0] = "A";
            alfabeto[1] = "B";
            alfabeto[2] = "C";
            alfabeto[3] = "D";
            alfabeto[4] = "E";
            alfabeto[5] = "F";
            alfabeto[6] = "G";
            alfabeto[7] = "H";
            alfabeto[8] = "I";
            alfabeto[9] = "J";
            alfabeto[10] = "K";
            alfabeto[11] = "L";
            alfabeto[12] = "M";
            alfabeto[13] = "N";
            alfabeto[14] = "O";
            alfabeto[15] = "P";
            alfabeto[16] = "Q";
            alfabeto[17] = "R";
            alfabeto[18] = "S";
            alfabeto[19] = "T";
            alfabeto[20] = "U";
            alfabeto[21] = "V";
            alfabeto[22] = "W";
            alfabeto[23] = "X";
            alfabeto[24] = "Y";
            alfabeto[25] = "Z";

            for (int i = 0; i <= alfabeto.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(alfabeto[i]);

                for(int iii = 0; i != 100; iii++)
                {
                    Console.Write("\n");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your inner loop is wrong:

```
            for(int iii = 0; i != 100; iii++)
            {
                Console.Write("\n");
            }
```

Depending on the the value of `i` this will either do nothing or loop forever.

It should be:

```
            for(int iii = 0; iii < 100; iii++)
            {
                Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
            }
```

In addition to fixing your loop counter, you were outputting the *string* `\n` rather than the newline character. You could also just use WriteLine with an empty string.

Now I look again, I see that your outer loop is also wrong. It should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < alfabeto.Length; i++)
```

If you loop to the count equal to the length you'll exceed the length of the array - a 26 element array has indices 0 to 25.

If you're not sure what the inner loop is doing I'd reduce the end test to something more manageable (5 for example) so you can see exactly how many lines are being inserted between each of your letters. You could also output the loop counter (as a debug measure) as an extra check

Comment: And outer too. Should be `i < alfabeto.Length;`

Comment: @elshev I changed like you(both) said and the exact same thing happens... It keeps adding new lines infinitely and no characters...

Comment: @RodrigoGameiro, this works for me. Maybe you just cannot see the characters because they are separated by 100 empty lines.

Comment: @botond.botos Assuming that is true (I must be blind...) why doesn't it stop printing empty lines?

Comment: I don't know why doesn't work for you, but please let me know once you find what was the problem in your version.

Answer (score 0):

Also notice that you have 101 line, not 100. Should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < alfabeto.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(alfabeto[i]);
    for (int iii = 0; iii < 100; iii++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
Console.Read();
```

Or you can simplify:

```
string s = new string('\n', 100);
for (char ch = 'A'; ch <= 'Z'; ch++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ch);
    Console.Write(s);
}
Console.Read();
```

Comment: It's correct, but also for good practice ... use `\r\n` or `Environment.NewLine` instead of `\n` for non Unix platforms